# How to init member object in declare time?

Tags: c++, initialization

Here is a class.

```
class Checker
{
public:
  Checker();
  ~Checker();

private:
  MapFileParser m_MapParser; //MapFileParser::MapFileParser(const char* path)

};
```

Is there have any way to init class member object when it is declaring another class? The `MapFileParser` class have only one constructer which has a signature like `MapFileParser::MapFileParser(const char* path)`. But I can't initialize when it is in class member. So i always initialize the `MapFileParser` member in `Checker` class's constructer.

Comment: Do you know that path during translation? I was writing the same answer as bellow when I realized it may not be applicable.

Comment: You said "during translation" means that in compile time?

Comment: Yes. Translation is what C++ standard uses. It's implementation agnostic.

Comment: Then , No I can't know the path in translation Time.

Comment: Then how do you expect to pass anything other than a default value? You must deliver it through the constructor.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry i Misunderstood that you said. I will fix the Checker() 's parameter void to const char * and the Checker(const char * Path) will pass the path to MapFileParser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

1. In-class member initialization syntax to initialize a member variable (possible only in C++11 or later).

   ```
   MapFileParser m_MapParser = MapFileParser("some sensible file name");
   ```
2. Initializer list syntax to initialize a member variable.

   ```
   Checker::Checker() : m_MapParser("some sensible file name") { ... }
   ```

The in-class member initialization syntax is helpful only if you have more than one constructor. If you have one constructor, you can use the initializer list syntax without loss of functionality.

If you have multiple constructors and you are able to use a C++11 or later compiler, you might be able to use the delegating constructors to reduce code duplication.

---

In a comment, you said:

> I will fix the Checker()'s parameter void to const char * and the Checker(const char * Path) will pass the path to MapFileParser.

In that case, the only solution will be to use member initialization list to initialize the member.

```
Checker::Checker(char const* path) : m_MapParser(path) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

From C++11 you can use [default member initializer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization), e.g.

```
class Checker
{
  ...
  MapFileParser m_MapParser{"something"};
  // or
  MapFileParser m_MapParser = MapFileParser("something");
};
```

Before C++11 you have to use [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list),

> Member initializer list is the place where non-default initialization of these objects can be specified.

e.g.

```
class Checker
{
public:
  Checker() : m_MapParser("something") {}
  ...
private:
  MapFileParser m_MapParser;
};
```

Comment: Thanks but how about before 11?

Comment: @HelloWorld - You are out of luck

Comment: @HelloWorld Answer revised.